# Basic Java Login Servlet Not working

Tags: java, ms-access, tomcat, servlets

I have created a msacess db **mydb.accdb** and pointed the odbc source to it and i have the following code in the lserv.java file all the necesary config for tomcat had been done and the servlet had no response so i added a print error in the init method which showed up the following error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet login threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    lserv.init(lserv.java:23)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The java code

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class lserv extends HttpServlet
{
Connection con;
ResultSet rs;
Statement st;
PrintWriter out;
public void init() 
{
try
{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mydb");
st=con.createStatement();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) 
{

try
{
out=res.getWriter();
res.setContentType("text/html");
if(req.getParameter("sub").equals("value"))
{
String s1=req.getParameter("t1");
String s2=req.getParameter("t2");
rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login WHERE uname='"+s1.trim()+"AND pass='"+s2.trim()+"';" );
if(rs.next())
{
out.println("welcome");
}
else
{
out.println("sorry");
}

}
}
catch(Exception e){
out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

The html page code

```
<html>
<title>Login System</title>
<style type="text/css">
div.ex {
width:220px;
padding:10px;
border:5px solid gray;
margin:10px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="ex">
<strong>User Login</strong>
<form name=f1 method=get action="http://localhost:8080/login">
User &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type=text name=t1><br>
Password <input type=password name=t2><br>
<input type=submit name=sub value="Login">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a table named login with field uname and pass with values.

What is the problem?Please help

Comment: one thing I would recommend doing is create a separate class and put all of your DB processing in that class. you can pass all the values from your servlet to that DB class. Also, you need to look at JSTL (google it) usebean to pass values to POJO classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be very clear;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    lserv.init(lserv.java:23)
    [...]
```

Just fix the NPE in line 23 of your code. :)

For me it looks like this line is causing the error:

```
out.println(e.getMessage());
```

The variable `out` is not initialized and therefore `null`.

Comment: if i remove out.println(e.getMessage()); there is no output at all

Comment: You should not remove it. You should fix the NullPointerException. Use System.out.println(e.getMessage) instead.

Comment: The fact that the NPE is thrown in the catch block tells you, that there is an exception when creating the DB connection. You should debug that.